# Python DataFrame: Why does my values change to NaN if I change the indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, nan

I want to change my indices. My dataFrame is as follows:

```
partA = pd.DataFrame({'u1': 2, 'u2': 3, 'u3':4, 'u4':29, 'u5':4, 'u6':1, 'u7':323, 'u8':9, 'u9':7, 'u10':5}, index = [20])
```

which gives a dataframe of size (1,10) with all cells filled.

However, when I create a new dataframe of this one (necessary in my original code which contain different data) and I change the index for this dataFrame, the values of my cells are all equal to `NaN`.

I know that I could use `reset_index` to change the index, but I would like to be able to do it all in one line.

What I did now is the following (resulting in NaNs)

```
partB = pd.DataFrame(partA, columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I','J'])
```

Comment: Please ask a new question with a new post instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 4):

You need `values` for converting `partA` to `numpy array`:

```
partA = pd.DataFrame({'u1': 2, 'u2': 3, 'u3':4, 'u4':29, 'u5':4, 'u6':1, 
                      'u7':323, 'u8':9, 'u9':7, 'u10':5}, index = [20])
print (partA)
    u1  u10  u2  u3  u4  u5  u6   u7  u8  u9
20   2    5   3   4  29   4   1  323   9   7

partB = pd.DataFrame(partA.values,columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I','J'])
print (partB)
   A  B  C  D   E  F  G    H  I  J
0  2  5  3  4  29  4  1  323  9  7
```

If need index from `partA`:

```
partB = pd.DataFrame(partA.values,
                     columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I','J'],
                     index = partA.index)
print (partB)
    A  B  C  D   E  F  G    H  I  J
20  2  5  3  4  29  4  1  323  9  7
```

You get `NaN` because not align column names, so if changed last name (`u7`), you get value:

```
partB = pd.DataFrame(partA,
                     columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I','u7'],
                     index = partA.index)
print (partB)
     A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   u7
20 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  323
```

Comment: Thanks! I added another question to my part above.

Comment: First question - I think the best is not create empty `DataFrame`, but rather create it by concated all small DataFrames to one, maybe parameter `keys` in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) is helpful.

Comment: Second question - can you add sample? but I think it is new question, not pandas, but python problem, so I think the best is create new one and some python guru can help you better as me.